# Slim и Cells в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Использую 'cells-rails', 'cells-slim'. Базовый класс cell:

```
class BaseCell < Cell::ViewModel
  def template_options_for(options)
    {
      template_class: ::Slim::Template,
      suffix: 'slim',
      disable_escape: false,
      escape_code: false,
      use_html_safe: true,
      buffer: '@output_buffer'
    }
  end
end
```

В самом классе например:

```
  def event_link
    link_to 'Event', list_events_path(start_time: recurrent[:base_start]) if recurrent
  end
```

И во вьюхе:
= edit_link

На выходе всегда:

> a href="/events/1/edit">Edit event

вместо нормальной ссылки. По идее, как раз use_html_safe должен отключать это экранирование всего и вся, но не делает этого, попытки использовать ==, raw, html_safe к ссылке никакого результата не дает, все html тэги также просто как текст. Как нужно настроить slim для нормальной работы с cells?

В readme к гему https://github.com/trailblazer/cells-slim написано Cells Slim change default settings for Slim and disables escaping in templates. А код выше (template_option) напротив включает escaping, но я пытался все настройки менять и убирать - ничего не менялось (собственно и включил я его для того, чтобы вручную править вместо include Cell::Slim сейчас там базовая настройка просто для примера).